# Javascript delay between turns

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a turn-based battle system in a RPG I'm building. I want the player to be able to see (through CSS) how his own and enemy's life lowers throughout the fight. 
This is my current code:

```
// Defining the variables globally for accessibility.
var enemy_max_hp = 0;
var enemy_hp = 0;
var enemy_atk_dmg = 0;
var enemy_def_pwr = 0;
var enemy_crit_chance = 0;
var enemy_crit_pwr = 0.0;

function battle() {
    while(current_hp > 0 || enemy_current_hp <= 0){
        //setTimeout(function(){
            current_hp -= enemy_atk_dmg*enemy_crit_pwr*crit_chance/100 + def_pwr/2;
            enemy_hp -= attack_dmg*crit_power*crit_chance/100 - enemy_def_pwr/2;

            if(current_hp < 0){ current_hp = 0; }
            if(enemy_hp < 0){ enemy_hp = 0; }

            if (current_hp == 0){
                // Die
            }

            if (enemy_current_hp == 0){
                // Win battle, proceed.
                    spawnenemy();
            }
        //}, 1000);
    }
}

function spawnenemy() {
    enemy_max_hp = 150;
    enemy_hp = 150;
    enemy_atk_dmg = 5;
    enemy_def_pwr = 3;
    enemy_crit_chance = 0;
    enemy_crit_pwr = 0;
}
```

I'm updating the user's data via another script:

```
var max_hp = 100;
var current_hp = 100;
var attack_dmg = 5;
var defense_power = 4;
var crit_chance = 0;
var crit_power = 0.0;

function showStats(){
    document.getElementById("max_hp").innerHTML = max_hp;
    document.getElementById("current_hp").innerHTML = current_hp;
    document.getElementById("attack_dmg").innerHTML = attack_dmg;
    document.getElementById("defense_power").innerHTML = defense_power;
    document.getElementById("crit_chance").innerHTML = crit_chance + '%';
    document.getElementById("crit_power").innerHTML = crit_power;
}
setInterval(showStats, 5);
```

If I run the code, as is, the battle ends in matter of an eyeblink, and health runs from 100 to 0 in an instance. I figured adding the setTimeout() function would work, but it just crashes the webpage. What should I do?

Also, the battle function is called (per now) via a button onclick call. I tried making a turn() function, but I miserably failed.

On a side note, I try to avoid any use of external packages. I have never touched jQuery or Angular2, and per now I won't use it. If any of you know a solution using it, though, feel free to share it. I don't care much about backwards-compatibility, either, tbh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SetTimeout (kindof) spawns a separate process, which starts life of it's own. The code, where this is called doesn't stop.

You should do something like this:

```
function battle(){

    if(current_hp > 0 || enemy_current_hp <= 0){

        // do your win thing

    } else {

        // do your fight thing

        // next round in 1 second
        setTimeout(battle, 1000);

    }

}
```

Using setTimeout for such purposes is better idea than setInterval, as you don't have to clear them and they won't get crowded - if your fight takes longer than period, then this won't run into next fight.

About jQuery, instead of long js selectors like this:

```
document.getElementById("max_hp").innerHTML = max_hp;
```

in jQuery you can write:

```
$('#max_hp').html(max_hp);
```

Additionally, setInterval with 5 millisecond period is kind of dangerous, especially on slower computers. Use at least 17 ms interval, or even 100ms. Normal human beings won't see updates less than 100 ms anyway.

Comment: This actually seems like a pretty clear approach to self-calling. How did I not see this myself? I don't understand your explanation regarding threading though.

Comment: Asyncronous is (not 100%) synonym for threading. When you call timeout, interval or event in your code, these functions start to run in parallel with the rest of the code. This means, that a) your "parent" code jumps over these calls and b) you can't guarantee, which code reaches what points before (you have to create some kind of locking system). For example, in your original code the showStats() does it's thing asynchronously, not looking at the rest of the code.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `battle` function to the following:

```
function battle() {
    var t = setInterval(function() {
        if(current_hp > 0 || enemy_current_hp <= 0) {

            // code to update battle stats

        } else {
            clearInterval(t);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

The problem with your code is that `setTimeout` and `setInterval` are asynchronous functions -- i.e., JavaScript will not wait for the them to finish, and thus your while loop is creating an infinite number of them and crashing your program. because it is halting for the timeouts to finish.

This modified program will instead run the code inside the `setInterval` block every second without creating an infinite loop. Once the battle is ended, it will clear the `setInterval`.

Comment: Mind explaining what asynchronousity is? How does it create an infinite amount of setTimeouts, if the setTimeout must finish before it can be called again?

Comment: @mazunki Being *asynchronous* means exactly the opposite of that: `setTimeout` doesn't finish before it is called again, but rather its timer is started and JS continues to run other code. The opposite is a *synchronous* operation, which goes to completion before going on to the following lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a `while` loop, use the decision to set a new timeout as the flow control in the program.  Also, I don't see a need for stats to update every 5 ms.  Just include showStats() in the battle when things change.   Something like:

```
function battleStep() {
    current_hp -= enemy_atk_dmg*enemy_crit_pwr*crit_chance/100 + def_pwr/2;
    enemy_hp -= attack_dmg*crit_power*crit_chance/100 - enemy_def_pwr/2;
    if(current_hp < 0){ current_hp = 0; }
    if(enemy_hp < 0){ enemy_hp = 0; }
    // now update the DOM with the new values
    showStats();
    if (current_hp == 0){
        // Die
    } else if (enemy_current_hp == 0){
        // Win battle, proceed.
        spawnenemy();
    } else {
        setTimeout(battleStep, 1000);
    }
}

function battle() {
    // initialize anything you need for the battle to start
    battleStep();
}
```

Comment: Values can change depending on a series of events. I figured a live updator was good enough. Your battleStep() is a nice apporach, thanks :)